# Distorted Display of Textbox infront of Datagrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, componentone

Please check out this image [image: http://postimage.org/image/ejdo207rz/]

When I display a textbox in front of a component one datagrid the text box displays like above.
If I position the textbox where it is not in front of the datagrid it displays fine.
Any ideas why? possible solutions?

Comment: Try setting the ZIndex to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by reading this article http://www.rqna.net/qna/znvkk-wpf-richtextbox-selected-text-distorted.html

This line of code in the xaml.cs constructor seems to clear it up.

```
RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

It is still slightly blurry but at least readable now.